# What does Wordpress media uploader do to image files on upload?

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

This question is specifically for images and what optimisation happens to these files when they are uploaded via Wordpress Media Library?

```
    Images
    .jpg
    .jpeg
    .png
    .gif
```

And how is it possible to change these settings?
I also know you can change the image sizes in `Settings > Media`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Wordpress only apply jpeg compression and the quality can be only change by code. For example, add this code to the functions.php file of your theme or in a plugin:

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){
    //Set compression quality from 0 to 100
    return 100;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Cybmeta that's supa easy, my images are usually optimized by time they make it to Wordpress, with JPEGmini and ImageOptim.

Comment: The optimization is not the same that jpeg compression quality. There is an excellent plugin for image optimization withing Wordpress, [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/), and it is free, but it consumes high server resources.